# USB mount doesn't work on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, mount, usb, usb-drive

I have a problem. After an update, my USB drives are not mounted automatically and I'm unable to mount them manually...

The output of my `fdisk -l` command is:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.8 GB, 15762194432 bytes
2 heads, 63 sectors/track, 244329 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 126 * 512 = 64512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x018d6a09

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1      244330    15392736    b  W95 FAT32
```

I tried with

```
mount -t nfs /mnt/usb /dev/sdb1
```

but it dowsn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use mount command as below :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
```

it will check and automatically detect and mount filesystem i.e `vfat`

Comment: It says me `mount: only root can do that`

Comment: Do it as root, then.

Comment: I did it. But I'm logged in with another user...

Comment: This is a solution. But one question: if I'm logged in with another user, I have to manually copy from terminal files in the usb device. I would copy them with drag and drop, not with the _cp_ command

Answer (score 1):

If `mount` is an issue and your system uses udisks try:

```
udisks --mount /dev/device
e.g.:
udisks --mount /dev/sdc1
```

And / or have a look at e.g.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

And mount by e.g.:

```
udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/MyUSBDevice
```

etc.

Comment: Cannot find device with major:minor 8:17: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

Comment: For USB devices you would most likely use `udisks` as if correctly set up it does not require mount privileges etc. (You won't have to sudo it). Try running `udisks --monitor` and re-plug device. It should be detected and mounted. Check system logs etc. and debug from there.

Comment: Nothing... the monitor didn't see my usb device....

Comment: `udevadm monitor` and check log files; e.g. `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: With this command I see something when I plug in the usb device. But I don't have a syslog file..

Comment: Try `dmesg | tail -n 50` (Where -n XX is how many lines you want). Else you have to find out [where your system log "things"](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-logfiles.html). You should probably also have a look at boot logs etc. `ls -l /var/log/`

Answer (score 1):

create a directory on for example:

```
/home/YourUserName/Desktop/MyUsb
```

Then run the command:

```
$ mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /home/YourUserName/Desktop/MyUsb

-t vfat = for msdos (fat-fat16-fat32 etc.)
-t ntfs = for ntfs
-t ext2 = for ext2
-t ext3 = for ext3
-t ext4 = for ext4
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux systems and many Unix systems, entries in the file `/etc/fstab` govern whether and where a device is mounted at startup.  Use the command `man fstab` for details about fstab entries.  Here are some examples:

```
/dev/sdf1  /sf1  fuseblk user,rw,nosuid,nodev,noauto 0 0
/dev/sdg3  /sg3  ext2    user,auto,nosuid,nodev      0 0
UUID=994228d4-etc-7f1d7d0 /usr   ext4 defaults       0 2
```

Items with a `user` keyword in them allow the user to mount or umount the corresponding device without needing to use `sudo` or `su`.  Items with `auto` mount automatically on system startup (and if not present may cause startup problems).  Items with `rw` are mounted read-write.

When fstab entries specify both a device and a mount point the mount command only needs to give one of them. For example, given the above entries, `/dev/sdf1` can be mounted by the user at `/sf1` by either of the following commands:

```
mount /sf1
mount /dev/sdf1
```

On linux systems or Unix systems with `/proc` you can see a list of partitions, mounted or not, via

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

If you know the UUID's of partitions on your USB drive, you can use the UUID instead of the device name in its fstab entry.  On some linux systems, use

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

to see the correspondence of UUID's and devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am using centOS 7 with the Mate desktop. I ran into a the problem of not being able to mount a USB disk. Short answer. Make sure that you have the desired users that you want to be able to mount USB devises  to the  disk group.